# ¿Cómo llamar a los elementos de una lista dentro de una función?

Tags: python

Tengo este programa que me devuelve verdadero o falso si la frase insertada es un palíndromo o no. Estoy tratando de lograr que la función evalúe la frase sin importar si tiene caracteres especiales, es decir no los tome en cuenta.
Creé una lista con los caracteres especiales y usé el método `contains` pero me da un error al decirme que no se pueden usar listas con esa función.
He tratado de llamar a la lista de otras maneras dentro de la función para hacer lo que quiero, pero no lo he conseguido.

```
caracteres = [".",",",";",":","!","¡","¿","?","´","¨"]

def es_palindromo(cadena):
    cadena = cadena.replace(" ","")
    cadena = cadena.lower()
    cadena = cadena.replace(caracteres[cadena], "")
    return cadena == cadena[::-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que `replace` no acepta una lista como parámetro, solo acepta una cadena. La solución para esto es simple:

```
Usar un bucle for.
```

Código:

```
caracteres = [".",",",";",":","!","¡","¿","?","´","¨"]

def es_palindromo(cadena):
    cadena = cadena.replace(" ","")
    cadena = cadena.lower()
    for char in caracteres:
        # Recorremos todo el array caracteres y reemplazamos los caracteres que coinciden por nada uno a la vez
        cadena = cadena.replace(char, "")
    return cadena == cadena[::-1]

print("¿haoloah es un palindromo?: "+str( es_palindromo("haoloah") ));
print("¿haol;:,!oah es un palindromo?: "+str( es_palindromo("haol;:,!oah") ));
```

Salida:

```
¿haoloah es un palindromo?: True
¿haol;:,!oah es un palindromo?: True
```